# One to Many type arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

I have worked a lot for the following scenario, but I couldn't get the desired output.

I am stuck at the scenario where I have:

```
Arraylist1 = {10,20,30};
Arraylist2 = {4,5,7}
```

and I want output as:

```
Combined: [10, 4, 10, 5, 10, 7, 20, 4, 20 ,5, 20, 7, 30, 4, 30, 5, 30, 7]
```

All I that I have manged is following:

```
 ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
 numbers.add(10); numbers.add(20); numbers.add(30); numbers.add(40);


 ArrayList<Integer> numbers2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
 numbers2.add(4); numbers2.add(5); numbers2.add(7);

 List<Integer> interleaved = interleave(numbers, numbers2);

 System.out.println("\nCombined: " + interleaved);


 public static List<Integer> interleave(final List<Integer> list1, final List<Integer> list2) {
     List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>(list2.size() + list1.size());

     Iterator<Integer> it1 = list1.iterator();
     Iterator<Integer> it2 = list2.iterator();
     while (it1.hasNext() || it2.hasNext()) {
         if (it1.hasNext()) {
             result.add(it1.next());
         }
         if (it2.hasNext()) {
             result.add(it2.next());
         }
     }
     return result;
 }
```

But the output I get is

```
Combined: [10, 4, 20, 5, 30, 7]
```

I want output to be like

```
Combined: [10, 4, 10, 5, 10, 7, 20, 4, 20 ,5, 20, 7, 30, 4, 30, 5, 30, 7]
```

Comment: Don't use the iterator for that problem, get the elements like a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your are going about your loops wrong.

Essentially what you need to do.

1. For every element in the first list loop.
2. For every element in the second list, add first element, then add second element.

i.e

```
for(Integer intval1 : list1)
{
   for(Integer intval2: list2)
   {
      result.add(intval1);
      result.add(intval2);
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You should not iterate both the lists in parallel. You need a nested for loop. Something like this:

```
for elem1 in list1
    for elem2 in list2
        add elem1 to result
        add elem2 to result
```

Just convert the pseudo code to enhanced for loop or to while loop with iterators. Drawback with iterator is you would need to re-create the iterators for `list2` for each outer loop iteration.

Comment: Thanks.I was confused as to how I should iterate over the two array lists.Thanks for correcting.

Answer (score 0):

I think your interleave method should be:

```
List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>(list2.size()
     + list1.size());
for (int i : list1) {
  for (int j : list2) {
    result.add(i);
    result.add(j);
  }
}
return result;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your interleave method to.

What we want is:

- **For every element in first list,every element of second list to be added**

So we wil add these elements into the inner for loop

```
public static List<Integer> interleave(final List<Integer> list1,
            final List<Integer> list2) {
        List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for (Integer num : list1) {

            for (Integer num2 : list2) {
                result.add(num);
                result.add(num2);
            }

        }

        return result;
    }
```

You do not need `Iterator` for that purpose. Use enhanced for loop as above.

Not sure whether it server your purpose, but you can have a key value pair for your lists also.

```
Map<Integer,List<Integer>> map = new ArrayList<Integer, List<Integer>>();
for(Integer num : list1 ){
    map.put(num,list2);
}
```

Here you can create key value pairs if you want one to many relatioship

Answer (score 0):

You can change the loop for this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list1.size(); i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < list2.size(); j++){
            result.add(list1.get(i));
            result.add(list2.get(j));
        }
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void listEntryCalc()
    {
        ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        numbers.add(10);
        numbers.add(20);
        numbers.add(30);
        numbers.add(40);


        ArrayList<Integer> numbers2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        numbers2.add(4);
        numbers2.add(5);
        numbers2.add(7);

        List<Integer> finalList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Integer integer : numbers)
        {
            for (Integer integer1 : numbers2)
            {
                finalList.add(integer);
                finalList.add(integer1);
            }
        }

        System.out.println("list " + finalList);
    }
```

**Output  is :**

```
[10, 4, 10, 5, 10, 7, 20, 4, 20, 5, 20, 7, 30, 4, 30, 5, 30, 7, 40, 4, 40, 5, 40, 7]
```